# Python nestled lists: recursion seems to stop too early

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested

I am trying to scan a nested list via recursion (code below). This works fine if the nested list stops with a list.
Example (python 3):

```
ok = [1,2,3,4,[5,6]] works fine i.e. output is 1 2 3 4 5 6
nok = [1,2,3,4,[5,6],7] does not print the "7". i.e. output is 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

There are probably better ways to flatten the nested list. I am just trying to understand what I am missing here i.e. where is the "7"?

```
def print_list (x):
    for i in x:
        if isinstance (i, list):
            return (print_list(i))
        else:
            print (i)

def main():
    a=[1,2,3,4,[5,6],7]
    print_list (a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: remove the `return` statement, it should work if you only need to print the list elements

Comment: The return statement breaks the for loop, if you don't want to exit the loop remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return before you reach the last element (`7`) of your outer list:

```
print_list(i)
```

instead of

```
return (print_list(i))
```

should do. `return` ends the function right there!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `return`, it will work fine.

```
def print_list (x):
    for i in x:
        if isinstance (i, list):
            print_list(i)
        else:
            print (i)

def main():
    a=[1,2,3,4,[5,6],7]
    print_list (a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `return` makes it work.

```
def print_list (x):
    for i in x:
        if isinstance (i, list):
           print_list(i)
        else:
            print (i)

def main():
    a=[1,2,3,4,[5,6],7]
    print_list (a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```